# How to Write a timer in mac80211

Tags: driver, wifi, linux-device-driver

How can I write a timer in mac80211 to periodic send a Frame?

And how can I call the other function by transmit the corresponding parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Checking my Ubuntu's clock sources:

cat /sys/devices/system/clocksource/clocksource0/available_clocksource 
hpet acpi_pm

As possibly the outdated RTC, these are all the possible clock sources available.

the mac80211 hardware does not have the timer functionality - NORMALLY.....cannot generalize for all.

Anyway, given these available clocksource, just have to a register an event with the timer to wake periodically to send out data via mac80211.

For example, use this as a base:

http://blog.fpmurphy.com/2009/07/linux-hpet-support.html